# UIScrollView with optimised visible area

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I'm implementing a UIScrollView for a social media stream. The items in the stream are customised UIVIews of varying size and complexity (sub views, images et al).

Im using MGBox2 controls for the UI and RestKit for the API communication.

The complexity is that I'm calling paged results from the server and displaying them in an infinitely scrollable stream, like the Google plus, pinterest, facebook apps. The UIScrollView will require that as it scrolls, items drop off the view or get rendered into it on the fly. I can also pull to refresh the latest activity, so the scroll view contents need to be updated above and below the current location of the scrollview

Does anyone have a good piece of sample code or a link for a smart way to optimise the ScrollView for such an implementation?

Thanks,
Hamish.